# Stringsplit, but in it is a * , how to solve this?

Tags: bash, split, quoting

I'm trying to run the following:

```
STR="M02093:93:000000000-ACE73:1:1105:25712:12098   0   hairpin_hsa-let-7a-1    5   255 23M *   0   0   ATGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT"
IFS='$'\t' read -ra NAMES <<< "$STR"   

#Print all names from array
for i in "${NAMES[@]}"; do
    echo ${NAMES[@]}
    echo $i
done
```

I want all fields, but in this example is a *, which would be a wildcard, then I get all files and directories in between of this string of the current directory. How can I solve this? This is how it looks:

```
M02093:93:000000000-ACE73:1:1105:25712:12098
0
hairpin_hsa-let-7a-1
5
255
23M
bla.sh test.txt
0
0
ATGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT
```

Comment: You should try using quotes in the echo command
    
    echo "$i"

Comment: Should be `IFS=$'\t'`; is that a typo in your post?

Comment: As usual, the answer is *quote your parameter expansions*!

Comment: thanks to @chepner and the others for your comments, they helped